# Dynamic select KnowledgeArticleVersion by Language

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, knowledge

I have the following code:

```
List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = [SELECT Title, UrlName, FirstPublishedDate, Summary, ArticleType, LastModifiedDate
                    FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion
                    WHERE isVisibleInApp=:isInternal AND isVisibleInCsp=:isCustomer AND isVisibleInPkb=:isPublic
                    AND IsVisibleInPrm=:isPartner AND PublishStatus='Online' AND Language=:selectedLanguage];
System.debug('articles = ' + articles);
```

and I certainly fetch error:

> Error 4   Implementation restriction:
>
> When querying the KnowledgeArticleVersion object, you must filter
>   using the following syntax: Id = [single ID], Id IN [list of ID's] or
>   Language = [language ISO code]. In addition Language is only permitted
>   in a top-level AND condition.

But after replacing var **selectedLanguage** on **'en_US'** soql works fine.

```
List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = [SELECT Title, UrlName, FirstPublishedDate, Summary, ArticleType, LastModifiedDate
                    FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion
                    WHERE isVisibleInApp=:isInternal AND isVisibleInCsp=:isCustomer AND isVisibleInPkb=:isPublic
                    AND IsVisibleInPrm=:isPartner AND PublishStatus='Online' AND Language='en_US'];
                    System.debug('articles = ' + articles);
```

Really I can`t select articles with dynamic lang?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can select articles dynamically, you need to use dynamic soql.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm